# Why can GCC only do loop interchange optimization when the int size is a compile-time constant?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, x86, compiler-optimization

When I compile this snippet (with `-Ofast -floop-nest-optimize`) gcc generates assembly which traverses the array in source order.

However, if I uncomment the line `// n = 32767` and assign ***any*** number to `n`, it interchanges the index order to `x[i * n + j]`.  Traversing memory in contiguous row-major order is much more cache-friendly than striding down columns.

```c
float matrix_sum_column_major(float* x, int n) {
    // n = 32767;
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sum += x[j * n + i];
    return sum;
}
```

[**On godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:30,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:30,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:30,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:30,startLineNumber:1),source:%27float+matrix_sum_column_major(float*+x,+int+n)+%7B%0A++++//+n+%3D+32767%3B%0A++++float+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+n%3B+i%2B%2B)%0A++++++++for+(int+j+%3D+0%3B+j+%3C+n%3B+j%2B%2B)%0A++++++++++++sum+%2B%3D+x%5Bj+*+n+%2B+i%5D%3B%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg93,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-Ofast+-floop-nest-optimize%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

**Why can't GCC or clang do [loop interchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange) with a runtime-variable `int` size?**  Real-world code won't usually have the size declared explicitly.

PD: I've tried this with different versions of gcc and clang-9 and it seems to happen in both.
PD2: Even if I make `x` be a local variable `malloc`ed inside the function it still happens.

Comment: Does it help to use `size_t` or any other unsigned type, such that `j*n` can't possibly encounter signed overflow UB?  Compiling for x86-64 using a 32-bit index makes life hard for GCC.  It can widen it to avoid redoing sign-extension every iteration based on signed overflow being UB (and the loop bound being written that way), but it might be harder to do more aggressive xforms.

Comment: Think about what would happen if you passed a negative number in `n`.  In the future, you might want to use `size_t` instead of `int` for variables used in array indices.

Comment: @technosaurus: negative `n` would make either loop condition initially false, regardless of which one was encountered first.  So whichever loop was outer-most would run zero times.  That's not the problem.  I tried on Godbolt and `unsigned` or `unsigned long long` don't help either (even if you also change the types of `i` and `j`.)  There is some change to the code-gen from `unsigned`, but it's not loop interchange; there's still a `add     rdx, rdi` or equivalent.  Oh, I think the unsigned n difference is just making sure zero-extension of unsigned `j*n` happens.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.   The current code is useless without a `main()` function to call it.

Comment: in real-world code, an `int` has a specific size.

Comment: @user3629249 the main problem is the indexing in the assembly generated, you can see it in the godbolt example.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers generally focus their efforts (and should focus their efforts) on places where constructs *which will likely be used by programmers interested in efficiency* can be replaced with other constructs *that are easily proven to be equivalent in all cases that should be expected to matter*.  If `n` is a constant, a compiler can determine the exact set of array indices that will be used in the loop and then figure out how to process all those indices.  If `n` isn't constant, a compiler might be able to determine that when `n` is positive, code will use all indices from `0` to `n*n-1`, but that would likely require a lot more effort.  The authors of clang and might have been able to make such a determination in this case if they tried hard enough, but they likely thought the effort wasn't worthwhile.

Note that if code will use a few particular values of `n` far more than any others, having code explicitly check for those values and use loops tailored for them, a compiler might be able to generate far more efficient code for those loops than would be possible for loops that can use an arbitrary `n`.  Because many real-world problems would likely have some values of `n` that get used much more than others, it would not be unreasonable for a compiler writer to assume that programmers interested in performance would be likely to use such special-purpose loops, and spending a certain amount of effort improving the arbitrary-`n` loop may offer less benefit than spending the same amount of effort elsewhere.

Comment: This is true normally, but SPECint2006 unfortunately contained a loop that benefited a huge amount from loop interchange, I think a column-major matrix loop.  Many of the major compilers thus invested effort into recognizing the optimization in at least the narrow circumstances of that one use-case.  This is why discussion of SPECint2006 results will often exclude or special-case the 462.libquantum test. https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=102569&curpostid=102580 discusses the Open64 compiler "cracking" libquantum; Sun's compiler was the first.

Comment: The SPECint2006 baseline that results are measured against (as a speedup factor) are a specific CPU and a specific compiler that *didn't* do this optimization.  So huge speedup factors like 1000 are possible for libquantum.  BTW, https://www.anandtech.com/show/14694/amd-rome-epyc-2nd-gen/9 mentions that GCC *doesn't* try to "break" libquantum or other benchmarks, so your general point holds for GCC.

Comment: A neat example of your special-case-of-a-value optimization is in glibc's integer->string function which takes a base as an arg.  https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/stdio-common/_itoa.c#L163 - It uses a macro to define a repeated-division loop, and a `switch` with `SPECIAL(10);` and 16 and 8, letting the compiler do constant-propagation into those 3 cases instead of dividing by a runtime variable.  This leads to a multiplicative inverse for `10`, and shift/AND for the powers of 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes: People seeking to produce quality compilers suitable for purposes other than running benchmarks should focus their efforts on processing their customers' code in whatever way best meets their customers' needs.  They should also put more focus on the time required to do something than the speed of doing it.  If a baseline program to do some task spends 50% of its time on subtask A and 50% on subtask B, an implementation that doubles the speed of both subtasks will generally have a more useful impact than one which doesn't affect subtask A, but speeds up subtask B by 1,000,000x.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Also, I'd like to see performance benchmarks expressed not in terms of time to run various programs, but rather in terms of time to accomplish a variety of tasks, using code which may be tailored to exploit any documented recommendations, including non-portable features.  Since the Standard lacks any way of giving compilers all the information necessary to accomplish many tasks in the most efficient ways that would meet requirements, efforts to maximize performance of "100% portable" programs could be better spent providing and exploiting extensions to improve performance.

Comment: Agreed with both points!  It's pretty silly that some compilers have spent significant effort to pattern-recognize some pretty narrow criteria that doesn't usually help other code.  But SPEC benchmarks sell hardware, and both Sun and Intel are (were) hardware vendors as well as compiler vendors. That explains why real-work market forces resulted in people doing this, even though well-informed people know that this is basically just wanking on the part of compiler devs. To be fair, compilers do already try to get all the general speedups they can, so a 50% everywhere speedup isn't a real option

Comment: @PeterCordes: Actually, for many tasks, some major optimization opportunities are left on the table.  For example, if a program has a requirement that it must never be observed to have performed incorrect computations as a result of integer overflow, but would allow integer overflow traps to occur any time between the start of program execution and the time when the incorrect calculations might affect human output, or would allow the program to produce arithmetically-correct output without trapping, optimal code to ensure that overflow will never produce incorrect output...

Comment: ...would often be much more efficient than optimal code to precisely trap integer overflows.  I don't know of any languages that would allow programmers to demand that compilers trap overflows that would produce observably incorrect output while granting compilers the freedom to produce correct output without overflow checking.  Requiring that user code perform manual overflow checking is disastrous from an optimization perspective.  If computes `x=y+z;` but `x` is never used, an automatic-overflow-checking implementation could omit the computation altogether.  Manual code to set an...

Comment: ...overflow flag if `y+z` won't fit in an `int`, however, would have an observable side effect in cases where `y+z` is out of range, regardless of whether code would otherwise care about that value.

Comment: *"The authors of clang apparently thought the effort was worthwhile, while those of gcc didn't."* I wasn't able to make clang optimize the indexing either, what setup did you use?

Comment: @MateodeMayo: Sorry--I misunderstood the post as asking why gcc couldn't do something that clang could.