# How do I get GCC to perform loop-interchange?

Tags: loops, gcc, optimization

GCC claims it will do loop-interchange in the following case (from the manpage)

```
   -floop-interchange
       Perform loop interchange outside of graphite.  This flag can
       improve cache performance on loop nest and allow further loop
       optimizations, like vectorization, to take place.  For example, the
       loop

               for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                 for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                   for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                     c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];

       is transformed to

               for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                 for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                     c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
```

but if I compile the following example with gcc -Ofast -mavx2 -mfma (Ofast -> O3 -> floop-interchange), I get two different versions, and the first one does not vectorize. Is there something wrong in the flags, or my function definitions? I have gcc 12.2.0 for x86-64.

```
#define N 10000

void matmul(double c[N][N], double a[N][N], double b[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
          c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
}

void matmul2(double c[N][N], double a[N][N], double b[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
          c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k]*b[k][j];
}
```

Comment: Sounds related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61016358/1983398).

Comment: @ssbssa yes, except the size is a compile-time constant in my case.

Comment: Does the result improve with `restrict`, like `void matmul(double c[restrict N][N], double a[restrict N][N], double b[restrict N][N])`?

Comment: @ssbssa It is able to vectorize the first version now, but still no loop-interchange.